# Can We Take the Potential at the Surface as the Potential at the Surface along with Potential at Infinity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

[image]

Here $V$ is the potential at surface and it is given to be zero, but I want to ask why does it hold that

$$
V_{surface} = V_{surface} + V_\infty
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here V is the potential at surface. 
>   Is nor correct.

$V$ is the potential of the surface $V_{\rm surface}$ relative to the potential at infinity $V_{\infty}$ ie the potential difference between the surface and infinity, so $V = V_{\rm surface} -V_{\infty} $